# How to format and add new numbers dynamically to hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get from server into client side only pure number IDs, how to add dynamically it to html hidden field so that looks like array or JSON format (I mean: `["32","33","34"]`), so that in next step I can receive on serwer and parse? Hidden field contains on start only blank brackets `[]`.

My current code override hidden field from `[]` to e.g. `"32"`:

```
$("#myHiddenField").val(JSON.stringify(data.result[0].newid));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to deserialize the array from the hidden input value, [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the new item, then serialize the array again:

```
var $hiddenField = $("#myHiddenField");
var results = $.parseJSON($hiddenField.val());
results.push(data.result[0].newid);
$hiddenField.val(JSON.stringify(results));
```

However, it might be more efficient to keep track of the array as items are added, and only serialize it when the form is submitted (in a [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event handler, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to parse the data in the hidden field, you can keep an actual array, push the new id to it, and serialise it to put in the hidden field:

```
var myArray = [];

myArray.push(data.result[0].newid);
$("#myHiddenField").val(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

---

Note: The JSON form of an array of numbers would be `[32,33,34]` rather than `["32","33","34"]`, and that is also what you get from the code above. If you want the format with the strings rather than numbers, add a `.toString()` before you push the value:

```
myArray.push(data.result[0].newid.toString());
```